# How do I add SQL auth to a C# forms app?

Tags: c#, sql, forms, authentication

I need to be able to verify a username and password against a sql server and I need code for a C# forms application.

I have it setup with 2 textboxes (1 user and 1 pass) and then I have a login button.

```
            SqlConnection UGIcon = new SqlConnection();
        UGIcon.ConnectionString = "Data Source=HP-PC//localhost;Initial Catalog=UGI;Integrated Security=True";
        UGIcon.Open();

        string userText = textBox11.Text;
        string passText = textBox12.Text;

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT stUsername,stPassword FROM LoginDetails WHERE stUsername='" + textBox11.Text + "' and stPassword='" + textBox12.Text + "'", UGIcon);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);

        if ( dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Login Success!!");
            cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT stRole from LoginDetails where stUsername=@stUsername", UGIcon);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stUsername",userText);
            string role = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
            MessageBox.Show(role);
            UGIcon.Close();
        }
        else 
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Access Denied!!");
            UGIcon.Close();
        }
```

Comment: Onclick make a sqlconnection and a sqlcommand and query your DB and get a sqldatareader which can read and verify the user

Comment: What have you tried? It is generally unacceptable to say "_I need code for ..._" on SO. We're here to help you, not to do your work for you.

Comment: So by _sql auth_ you weren't referring to the standard authentication providers (which would probably simplify your code and make it more complete)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a real believer in using the "using" statements.  You can also save yourself a 2nd query by asking for the stRole variable in the original query.  The using blocks will automatically dispose of the objects, so when execution leaves this area, the objects will automatically be cleaned up.

```
using (SqlConnection UGIcon = new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=UGI;Integrated Security=True"))
        {
            UGIcon.Open();

            string userText = textBox11.Text;
            string passText = textBox12.Text;

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT stUsername,stPassword, stRole FROM LoginDetails WHERE stUsername='" + userText + "' and stPassword='" + passText + "'", UGIcon);

            using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (rdr.HasRows)
                {
                    while (rdr.Read())
                    {
                        string role = rdr["stRole"].ToString();
                        MessageBox.Show(role);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Access Denied!!");
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Pls check this code

```
SqlConnection thisConnection = new
        SqlConnection(@"Server=(local)\sqlexpress;Integrated Security=True;" +
                  "Database=northwind");
        thisConnection.Open();
        SqlCommand thisCommand = thisConnection.CreateCommand();
        thisCommand.CommandText = "Select count(*) from UserDetails
WHere UserName = "+txtUsername.text.trim().toLower() + " and Password = " +txtPassword.text.trim().toLower();
        Object countResult = thisCommand.ExecuteScalar();
        Console.WriteLine("Count of Customers = {0}", countResult);

        thisConnection.Close();
```

Comment: I am using a forms app not console app and where do I add the IP for a remote address do I just replace (local)?

Comment: @John_Dong - The code provided in this answer could easily be adapted to WinForms.

Comment: Yeah I just noticed do you happen to have the SQL query to send to the sql server to add users and passwords by any chance?

Comment: @John_Dong - See my comment above. Using the standard auth providers will provide this functionality for you (among others) without having to write much code at all. Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: I understand that but how do I add users to my sql database now?

Comment: I know C# but I don't know SQL at all and I barely use it.

Comment: INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3,...)
 VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...)